# Can someone copy http-only cookie from client pc?

Tags: cookie-httponly

I searched about it on the internet but didn't find anything. As we know http-only cookie immune to xss attack, but my concern is what if someone copy it from client pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of `HttpOnly` cookies is that they can't be accessed by JavaScript.
Reading http-only cookie is always forbidden on the latest version of all major browsers.
But more importantly why do you want to read an `HTTPOnly` cookie if you are not an attacker?

And someone can not copy `HttpOnly` cookies. Its purpose is being inaccessible by script.

Comment: I am not an attacker. I just want to save the jwt key securely so no one can get it by xxs attack and by inspecting the devtool in the browser.

Comment: If you got the answer, check the solved button.

Comment: I researched on the internet again and I found that is it possible to copy the httponly cookie and use it in other browser without any error. You can read it here https://salferrarello.com/httponly-cookies/

Comment: @AbhijeetSingh, Sorry, but you're confused that's why you're not pleased with the answer. First of all, the author Sal Ferrarello already mention the same thing: "I could not read the cookie with JavaScript". 
As for copying `HttpOnly` cookies, if you want to take precautions to prevent this from being copied, already there are tons of topics on the internet and one of them is clearly mentioned in the site you referred: "You can create cookies that can only be accessed server side(not via JavaScript)"

Comment: Httponly cookies are only accessible by the server, yes but because we can create httponly cookie using developer tool in browser, anyone can copy it manually(physically) from target pc to another and can login. We can prevent it as you mention there are lots of topics on internet, one of the solutions that I like adding some device identification.

Comment: So, that is a subject for another question. I can mention that device identification is used by many web-sites. It succeeds once it's implemented well. And not only MAC address should be considered since it may cause further UI-UF problems. As already I said, it's a subject for another question. Making a fuss here is unnecessary. I hope, you found an answer for this question. However, if that's not the answer you've been looking for, that may be because you did not ask it well. As this topic only encapsulating `Can someone copy http-only cookie from client pc`. And the shortest answer is no.

Comment: Besides, I assume that breaking well-secured systems also is possible should be mentioned. But the shortest answer will always be `no`. Nothing more than it :) Maybe you should ask the question this way:"How can I prevent `HttpOnly` cookie from being copied?"

Comment: My apologies, I wrote in description, maybe I should have written a little more clearly. Anyway, thanks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: No apologies are needed. It's possible to lose the aim when you don't even know where to start. [I think, this tutorial will help you.](https://cheatcode.co/tutorials/how-to-implement-secure-httponly-cookies-in-node-js-with-express)
And as already I said, if it solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as solved unless you ask again or set bounty for this question.